# G_Settings apply changes

Tags: settings, gnome

Im doing some C coding but im unable to store g_settings permanently!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>


#include <gio/gio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  GSettings *settings;
  g_type_init();
  settings = g_settings_new ("org.nemo.desktop");
  printf("%s\n", g_settings_get_string(settings, "font"));
  g_settings_set (settings, "font", "s", "Arial");
  if (g_settings_get_has_unapplied (settings)) printf("X");
  printf("%s\n", g_settings_get_string(settings, "font"));
  return 0;
}
```

Trying on Linux Mint 13 Cinnamon (paths,etc. are correct).

Comment: You say "paths,etc. are correct" but don't check g_settings_set() return value.

Comment: Return value is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I misread your code at first... I believe you should call `g_settings_sync ()` if you want to ensure your changes are written to disk. Apparently if you run without a mainloop (like in your example case) this is really required to get things on disk at all.

So, just to be clear: a normal application with a glib mainloop will not need (and shouldn't really use) a sync-call.

Comment: Great this helped! Im in debt... if u would sometime come in CZE i ll buy u beer :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t a minimal working example. Could you provide the schema file you’re using?

Compiling your code with `` gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gio-2.0` -o temp temp.c `` and using the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schemalist>
    <schema id="org.nemo.desktop" path="/org/nemo/desktop/">
        <key name="font" type="s">
            <default>''</default>
            <summary>Summary</summary>
            <description>Description.</description>
        </key>
    </schema>
</schemalist>
```

which I installed with:

```
sudo cp org.nemo.desktop.gschema.xml /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

I get the following output, which seems to be correct:

```
Arial
```

Comment: Output is correct, but the change is not permanently ... Try if it changes your permanently ... (or with org.gnome.background) (picture-uri) ... Output is correct, but problem is, that it doesnt affect the background (which gets affected by python script)

Comment: `code` <schema path="/org/nemo/desktop/" id="org.nemo.desktop" gettext-domain="nemo">
    <key type="s" name="font">
      <default l10n="messages" context="desktop-font">''</default>
      <summary>Desktop font</summary>
      <description>The font _description used for the icons on the desktop.</description>
    </key>
`code`

This is that schema... 

As said before, it is working only temporary